# Document ready fires, but its attached function does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

I'm an application engineer at heart and new to Javascript, but I'm learning quickly since I undertook an assignment at the office involving porting our internal testing site over to a new UI. Obviously I will try to post little code so as not to compromise anything the company might think sensitive. I've searched high and low for an answer to this one, and after putting `$.isReady` into the Chrome debugger and receiving true, I waved the white flag and decided to ask on here.

I have a strange issue where my `$(document).ready()` call fires, but the function contained within the `.ready()` parameters does not. Here's the function itself:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
        $.getJSON('/Home/RetrieveServersJson', function (data) {
            servers = data;
            for (i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
                if (servers[i].IsGT)
                    gtServers[length] = servers[i];
                else
                    mrSixSservers[length] = servers[i];
            }
            alert(servers.length + " " + mrSixSservers.length + " " + gtServers.length);
        });
    });
```

As you may have guessed, the line at the beginning is just a test that modifies a `<p>` element which initially states "Not ready yet." The site is running jQuery 1.10.2. Here's a few things I've nailed down:

1. The call to `$(document).ready()` fires, from what I can tell. I've deduced this from the fact that a breakpoint placed on the function stops there, and I can then step through the jQuery library for a bit before the call resolves, but it never steps into the handler function even if I put a breakpoint there, instead returning to the top of the source code.
2. I am about as sure that I can be that this is not a problem with my script references. I'm using bundles to hold the scripts, but here's what the rendered scripts look like on the page:

   ```
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/excanvas.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/unicorn.js"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/unicorn.dashboard.js"></script>
   ```

   In addition, I have another page that uses the exact same script references and I tested a document ready function on there, which worked just fine.
3. All of my other Javascript functions and jQuery calls work exactly as they're supposed to.
4. I have tried reducing the ready function to nothing but an alert call, which did not work. I changed the alert call to a change in a `<p>` element just to see if the DOM was being delayed in readying.
5. At this point, I thought the DOM might not ever be showing ready. However, as I mentioned before, I put $.isReady into the Chrome debugger console and it returned true.
6. There are no syntax errors; I've gone through and made sure all the curly braces matched up.
7. In fact, the console doesn't show any errors apart from `Uncaught Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null`, which happens inside jquery.flot.min.js any time it is loaded.

Anyone know what might cause $.isReady to show true but a $(document).ready() function to simply not fire?

Comment: Are you sure that the getJSON is not erroring out?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? This would likely help us nail it down much faster.

Comment: Are you seeing the paragraph "The DOM is now loaded"?

Comment: @JessieA.Morris See #7 in the question.

Comment: @JessieA.Morris: "In fact, the console doesn't show any errors apart from Uncaught Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null, which happens inside jquery.flot.min.js any time it is loaded."

epascarello I don't know, but the ready function does not fire even if I take out the getJSON call and leave it with just an alert.

Barmar No.

Comment: Where are you including the scripts? A simple `$(function() { alert('foo') })` on this page, after the JS is loaded, simply doesn't work?!

Comment: That error you are getting is because you are trying to plot a flot chart somewhere with the wrong identifier but should break the getJSON call

Comment: @DaveNewton They're being included in the head, rendered as shown in the post.

Comment: can you make a simplified jsfiddle with the problem? If not, I suggest you start removing code and scripts - binary-search like, until you can get to the smallest case which reproduces. That will help you locate the issue.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC (as that looks like a typical route from the framework)? If so, you need to make sure your return expression is something along the lines of `return Json(/* your json */, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your point number 4 speaks volumes. To confirm, are you saying that you replaced the code posted in your question with just:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("I am here");
});
```

and it did not work?

If so, then the problem is definitely in one of your referenced script libraries.

Just as a test, I could suggest:

1. Eliminate all js code except the above "I am here" test.
2. Replace your bundled libraries with the broken out list you posted above:
3. Comment out all the above libraries *(except jQuery, of course, since you are testing with it)* and add back in one at a time until you identify the culprit.

If "I am here" works when scripts are referenced individually, then something is wonky with the script bundle.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was slightly bullheaded in eliminating the script libraries as the culprit so soon. I removed the call to render the big bundle (it renders everything except the calls for jquery.min, jquery-ui.custom, and bootstrap) and now the ready function fires just fine -- although now I have to figure out how I'm going to get the UI to run properly if I can't have the scripts necessary for it to function.

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  "error":function() { $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded but I got ajax error");  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still showing "Not ready yet." (the initial state of the element).

Answer (score 0):

I would re-re-recheck script references. The code is fine.

You could try removing your references, and add some hosted libraries, just to be sure.

```
<p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fcoeudnp/

**Edit:**

You could also just check if jQuery is ready with:

```
if ( jQuery.isReady ) {  
    alert('jQuery is ready');
}
```